# recorrer Json JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Quiero recorrer este Json para obtener sus valores y mostrarlos

```
[
    {
        "$id": "1",
        "Nombre": "Casa de las Conservas",
        "Descripcion": "",
        "Imagen": "",
        "Destino": "San Miguel de Allende",
        "Url": "https://www.mexicodestinos.com/san-miguel-de-allende/hoteles/casa-de-las-conservas.html",
        "PrecioDesde": 0,
        "PrecioDesdePromo": 0,
        "TienePromo": 0,
        "Servicio": "Hotel"
    },
    {
        "$id": "2",
        "Nombre": "Misión San Miguel de Allende",
        "Descripcion": "Este confortable y acogedor ho",
        "Imagen": "https://cdn.mexicodestinos.com/hoteles/hotel-mision-san-miguel-de-allende-princ.jpg",
        "Destino": "San Miguel de Allende",
        "Url": "https://www.mexicodestinos.com/san-miguel-de-allende/hoteles/hotel-mision-san-miguel-de-allende.html",
        "PrecioDesde": 568,
        "PrecioDesdePromo": 540,
        "TienePromo": 1,
        "Servicio": "Hotel"
    },
    {
        "$id": "3",
        "Nombre": "Misión San Miguel de Allende",
        "Descripcion": "Este confortable y acogedor ho",
        "Imagen": "https://cdn.mexicodestinos.com/hoteles/hotel-mision-san-miguel-de-allende-princ.jpg",
        "Destino": "San Miguel de Allende",
        "Url": "https://www.mexicodestinos.com/san-miguel-de-allende/hoteles/hotel-mision-san-miguel-de-allende.html",
        "PrecioDesde": 568,
        "PrecioDesdePromo": 540,
        "TienePromo": 1,
        "Servicio": "Hotel"
    },
    {
        "$id": "4",
        "Nombre": "Belmond Casa De Sierra Nevada",
        "Descripcion": "Belmond Casa de Sierra Nevada,",
        "Imagen": "https://cdn.mexicodestinos.com/hoteles/casa-de-sierra-nevada-san-miguel-de-allende-princ.jpg",
        "Destino": "San Miguel de Allende",
        "Url": "https://www.mexicodestinos.com/san-miguel-de-allende/hoteles/belmond-casa-de-sierra-nevada.html",
        "PrecioDesde": 0,
        "PrecioDesdePromo": 0,
        "TienePromo": 0,
        "Servicio": "Hotel"
    },
    {
        "$id": "5",
        "Nombre": "Misión San Miguel de Allende",
        "Descripcion": "Este confortable y acogedor ho",
        "Imagen": "https://cdn.mexicodestinos.com/hoteles/hotel-mision-san-miguel-de-allende-princ.jpg",
        "Destino": "San Miguel de Allende",
        "Url": "https://www.mexicodestinos.com/san-miguel-de-allende/hoteles/hotel-mision-san-miguel-de-allende.html",
        "PrecioDesde": 568,
        "PrecioDesdePromo": 540,
        "TienePromo": 1,
        "Servicio": "Hotel"
    }
]
```

Realicé el siguiente código

```
 $.ajax({
            data: parametros,
            type:"POST",
            url:"cUrl.php",
            success: function(res){
               //console.log(data);
               for(i=0;i<res.length;i++){
                 $('#lol').html("<strong><p>"+res[i]['Nombre']+"</p></strong>");
               }
            }
        });
```

Pero me devuelve valores undefine

Comment: lo revisé, pero no veo que sean iguales

Comment: el json puede ser diferente, pero tienen el `for` recorre un arreglo de json, ya que lo he probado y funciona correctamente

Comment: debes convertir el json _JSON.parse()_ que te llega en una arreglo.
`$.ajax({
            //data: parametros,
            type: "POST",
            url: "cUrl.php",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (res) {
                //console.log(data);
                var lst = JSON.parse(res.d);
                for (i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
                    $('#lol').html("<strong><p>" + lst[i]['Nombre'] + "</p></strong>");
                }
            }
        });`

Comment: No funciona esa forma